# umbraco cms error when building source code

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build the Umbraco cms source code within Visual Studio 2012 and keep getting the following error on the line below in PluginManager.cs

```
try
            {
               **var typeInstance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t);**
                instances.Add(typeInstance);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                LogHelper.Error<PluginManager>(String.Format("Error creating type {0}", t.FullName), ex);

                if (throwException)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
```

The error points to this line

```
**var typeInstance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t);**
```

and says 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: what is `t` in this case ? Apart from being null ^_^

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk if it is an error *at build*, then it would be unassigned, not null; but the OP doesn't make it clear whether this is build-time or runtime

Comment: @MarcGravell I won't argue with you M. Gravell. But still not enough information to answer :(